# Concatenating XML nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My requirement is to transform the following source XML into the destination XML. Could you please help me with the required XSLT?

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <property><namevalue name="loccode1">BIN01</namevalue></property>
    <property><namevalue name="locdesc1">Description for BIN01</namevalue></property>
    <property><namevalue name="loccode2">BIN02</namevalue></property>
    <property><namevalue name="locdesc2">Description for BIN02</namevalue></property>
    <property><namevalue name="loccode3">BIN03</namevalue></property>
    <property><namevalue name="locdesc3">Description for BIN03</namevalue></property>
</catalog>
```

Destination XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <property>
        <namevalue name="location1">BIN01#Description for BIN01</namevalue>
    </property>
    <property>
        <namevalue name="location2">BIN02#Description for BIN02</namevalue>
    </property>
    <property>
        <namevalue name="location3">BIN03#Description for BIN03</namevalue>
    </property>
</catalog>
```

The requirement is to concatenate the values of `namevalue` nodes with attributes `loccode<seq>` and `locdesc<seq>`. Could you please help me achieve this?

The following snippet

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/property/namevalue[@name='loccode2'] |  catalog/property/namevalue[@name='locdesc2']" />
```

is expecting me to specify the attribute name explicitly and the output is `BIN01Description for BIN01` (I am not even able to add a delimiter). Is there a way of dynamically passing the attribute (for e.g `loccode<seq>` or `locdesc<seq>`) and appending a delimiter between the copied text.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of dynamically passing the attribute (for e.g loccode or locdesc)

Yes. You could use:

```
/catalog/property[starts-with(namevalue/@name, 'loccode')]
```

to select only the `location codes` properties.

---

Alternatively, if the structure follows a regular pattern, you could use:

```
/catalog/property[position() mod 2 = 1]
```

to make the same selection, and then:

```
following-sibling::property[1]
```

to select the adjacent `location description` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this as alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property[namevalue[contains(@name, 'loccode')]]">
        <property>
            <xsl:for-each select="namevalue[contains(@name, 'loccode')]">
                <xsl:variable name="seq" select="concat('locdesc', substring-after(@name, 'loccode'))"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '#', //namevalue[@name = $seq])"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </property>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property[namevalue[contains(@name, 'locdesc')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see this link: http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBK/1

Answer (score -1):

```
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <catalog>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="property/namevalue">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'Description for ')"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <property>
                <namevalue>
                    <xsl:if test="@name">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('location', substring-after(@name, 'loccode'))"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'#','Description for ',.)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </namevalue>
            </property>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Plz check this code.